# dynamic memory allocation of struct member in different function

Tags: c++, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to do something like the snippet below:

```
using namespace std;

struct str {
    int *integs;
};

void allocator(str*& str1) {str1.integs=new int[2];}
void destructor(str*& str1) {delete [] str1.integs;}

int main () {

    str str1;
    allocator(str1);
    str1.integs[0]=4;
    destructor(str1);
    return 0;
}
```

However this doesn't work; I get *error: request for member ‘integs’ in ‘str1’, which is of non-class type ‘str*’*

Is this impossible to do with struct and I need a class? Do I have to use the -> operator somehow? Thoughts?

Comment: you access an object through a pointer and use the dot (`"."`) operator. use `->` instead, or take the parameter by reference (`str&` instead of `str*&`)

Comment: @jorgen: For clearer understanding on references : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/references.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking `str1` as a reference to a pointer. You probably meant:

```
void allocator(str& str1) {str1.integs=new int[2];}
void destructor(str& str1) {delete [] str1.integs;}
```

Answer (score 1):

str1 is a reference to a pointer, you should use

```
str1->integs
```

Or use it just as reference:

```
void allocator(str& str1) {str1.integs=new int[2];}
void destructor(str& str1) {delete [] str1.integs;}
```

And it should be fine